Azure Automation - How to invoke functions or variables defined in other runbooks with runtime Powershell 7.2
What I have:
I have two simple runbooks, init and main in Powershell runtime 7.2
init runbook, which contains some simple variables and funtions
$var1 = "hello"
$var2 = "world"

function Add-WB {
  param (
        [string]$P1, 
        [string]$P2
    )
  return "$P1 $P2"
}


main runbook, Try to get the variables defined in init runbook
What already tried -1:

main runbook physically invoke init runbook by . .\init.ps1

. .\init.ps1

$p1 = "wb1"
$p2 = "wb2"

Write-Output "test var1 in init.ps1 $var1"
Write-Output "test var2 in init.ps1 $var2"

Add-WB -P1 $p1 -P2 $P2

when in powershell runtime version = 5.1 result shows works well:

when in powershell runtime version = 7.2 result shows error:



What already tried - 2:

main runbook invoke init runbook by Start-AutomationRunbook -Name "init" or Start-AzAutomationRunbook
Start-AutomationRunbook -Name "init"

Start-Sleep 180

$p1 = "wb1"
$p2 = "wb2"

Write-Output "test var1 in init.ps1 $var1"
Write-Output "test var2 in init.ps1 $var2"

Add-WB -P1 $p1 -P2 $P2

result:
init runbook actullay be trigger to run (sleep enough time to wait run completion), but the function Add-WB or $var1, $var2 still not be usable in main runbook, not been infused when run main runbook



My question:
How can I share the variables or common-functions across the azure automation account runbooks

Resolved via a tricky way, not elegant but actually works

login and get azure access token
get and download the init runbook content to main runbook runtime sandbox. rest api reference
inject the functions and variables by dot run the init.ps1

$rgName = "xxx"
$autoName = "xxx"
$runbookName = "init"
$subscriptionId = "xxx"

Connect-AzAccount -Identity
Set-AzContext -Subscription $subscriptionId

$token1 = $(Get-AzAccessToken).Token

$headers1 = @{
    "Content-Type" = "application/json"
    "Authorization" = "Bearer " + $token1
}

$uri1 = "https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{0}/resourceGroups/{1}/providers/Microsoft.Automation/automationAccounts/{2}/runbooks/{3}/content?api-version=2023-11-01" -f $subscriptionId, `
$rgName, $autoName, $runbookName


Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Uri $uri1 -Headers $headers1 -OutFile '.\init.ps1'

. '.\init.ps1'

Write-Output "now in mainRunbook, getting from childrunbook var1 var2 : $var1 $var2"

AddWB -P1 "wb" -P2 "wb2"

